# Load TXT file (comma separated) with new line character in field into Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using `COPY INTO` command to load a CSV files and it works for 99% record except one where the field value has a new line character `\n` and it is not enclosed within double quotes `"` so irrespective of how I use `FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY` option while creating file format it does not help. Is there any possibility of loading this file with 100% records?

Example record (4 fields in a record)

```
value 1, value 2, valu
e3, value 4
```

Comment: Assuming your actual record delimiter is also the newline character then there is no way that Snowflake can fix your data for you and load it - you’ll need to fix the data yourself before you try and load it

Comment: Yes record delimiter is `\n`

Comment: If this is an isolated problem, as NickW pointed out it's easier to fix the file before ingestion. If it's a systemic problem that tends to happen from time to time and breaks pipelines, you'd need to define a landing table as all string types and then detect/consolidate any rows that have value count mismatches. You'd also need to treat nulls as temporarily a string value. You can then copy the rows into a clean table with proper data types.